# Ubuntu 16.04 on Google Compute - User Permission with www-data

Tags: linux, ubuntu

This question is more about Linux than the Google Compute Engine...but I can't seem to figure out the solution!

When I log into my compute server with my SSH key, I want to be able to modify files that are owned by www-data group and user.  But I can only modify files after I run this command `sudo chown TJNevis:www-data -R /var/www`.
Then I have some issues with the website code that doesn't like that the permissions aren't www-data:www-data, so I find I'm switching back and forth to be able to edit files via `SFTP` and then run properly on the site.  It's very annoying.

I've read about this issue a lot and tried a bunch of different commands, but nothing seems to work.  The most promising is this:

```
sudo adduser TJNevis www-data
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
sudo chmod -R g+rwX /var/www
```

But it's still not working for me.

I can confirm if I run `groups TJNevis` that `www-data` shows up, so I'm just confused why I can't edit files via SFTP without having me as the user.

Comment: This is `sudo chown TJNevis:www-data -R /var/www` a good option, and `sudo adduser TJNevis www-data` is the way. Did you restart the system to have it take effect?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran

`sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www`

and

`sudo chmod -R g+rwX /var/www`

I've confirmed that TJNevis is part of the www-data group:

`groups TJNevis`:
`TJNevis adm dialout cdrom floppy audio dip www-data video plugdev netdev lxd ubuntu google-sudoers`

Then I restarted.

Same issue, when I SFTP in with my SSH key, [I try to modify a file and I get this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzmKj.png).

Is it because I'm not in the sudoers group or root group?  I don't know, but this is driving me nuts.

I'd like to keep all the files www-data:www-data because some of the scripts will break on the sites I'm hosting if they aren't - some are third-party plugins and whatnot...I don't want to go in and modify their code just to have it overwritten with an update.  Saving to disk, I think the user and group would need to be www-data, so I'd really like to leave that alone.

I need to find a way for me to SFTP with my username and edit files without it yelling at me =).